# How can I match a CIDR range for an SSH config host entry?

Tags: ssh

I'm looking for a way to use specific CIDR blocks to match hosts in the SSH client configuration (usually `~/.ssh/config`). For example, I have an entry to forward all traffic through a bastion host if the IP falls into a certain range, let's say `10.1.0.0/16`:

```
host 10.1.*
    proxycommand ssh -q bastion -W %h:%p
```

This works very well, but how about when I add some ranges that don't fit the dot notation exactly?

```
# doesn't work, unfortunately
host 10.2.0.0/18
    proxycommand ssh -q bastion-foo -W %h:%p
host 10.2.64.0/18
    proxycommand ssh -q bastion-bar -W %h:%p
```

Is there something in the manual that I've missed, or a clever scripting trick that would enable matching these host IP ranges?

Answer (score 39):

Matching against patterns in the ssh_config file is done as basic pattern matching, not as a network/CIDR matching. So using CIDR notation is not going to work.

The [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#PATTERNS) explains that:

> A pattern consists of zero or more non-whitespace characters, `*` (a wildcard that matches zero or more characters), or `?` (a wildcard that matches exactly one character).

The best you can do is to use a list of more than one pattern. Again, from the manual page:

> A pattern-list is a comma-separated list of patterns.  Patterns within pattern-lists may be negated by preceding them with an exclamation mark (`!`).

So to cover your two /18 nets, you'd need to list:

- all hosts matching `10.2.?.*` (i.e. 10.2.0.0–10.2.9.255)
- all hosts matching `10.2.??.*` (i.e. 10.2.10.0–10.2.99.255)
- all hosts matching `10.2.10?.*` (i.e. 10.2.100.0–10.2.109.255)
- all hosts matching `10.2.11?.*` (i.e. 10.2.110.0–10.2.119.255)
- all hosts matching `10.2.12?.*` EXCEPT the ones matching `10.2.128.*` and `10.12.129.*` (and remember that the exclusion must come first!)

Your pattern list should then look like this:

```
Host "10.2.?.*","10.2.??.*", "10.2.10?.*","10.2.11?.*","!10.2.128.*","!10.2.129.*","10.2.12?.*"
```

Comment: To be precise, this is not a regular expression, it's a globbing wildcard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it nearly works for me but I actually needed to differentiate those two ranges with separate `host` entries. It also needed each one quoted separately (ssh/Mac). Shortest I could find:

`host "10.2.?.*", "10.2.??.*", "!10.2.64*", "!10.2.65*", "!10.2.66*", "!10.2.67*", "!10.2.68*", "!10.2.69*", "!10.2.7*", "!10.2.8*", "!10.2.9*"`

and 

`host "10.2.??.*", "10.2.10?.*", "10.2.11?.*", "10.2.12?.*", "!10.2.1?.*", "!10.2.2?.*", "!10.2.3?.*", "!10.2.4?.*", "!10.2.5?.*", "!10.2.60.*", "!10.2.61.*", "!10.2.62.*",
"!10.2.63.*", "!10.2.128.*", "!10.2.129.*"`

Answer (score 10):

You could use the very powerful [`Match` directive](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html#DESCRIPTION) with the [grepcidr](http://www.pc-tools.net/unix/grepcidr/) tool:

```
Match exec "grepcidr 10.2.0.0/18 <(echo %h) &>/dev/null"
   Proxycommand ssh -q bastion-foo -W %h:%p
```

How this works:

- `%h` in the commandline gets expanded to the hostname (see [Tokens](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html#TOKENS))
- `<(echo %h)` wraps this into a temporary "file"
- Maybe use `<(dig +short %h)` if working with hostnames
- then use `grepcidr` to match the hostname `%h` against a.b.c.d/e
- `&>/dev/null` because we only care about the return code, not the output.

This needs the additional tiny [grepcidr package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=grepcidr), which should exist in your package manager.

Answer (score 4):

Keep an eye on http://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1169 which may eventually provide a mechanism for this.

Comment: last comment 2014 ⌚⌚

Comment: OpenSSH developer [Damien Miller](https://twitter.com/damienmiller) recently responded to [my asking this on twitter](https://twitter.com/adamhotep/status/1337187110990696450) by saying “I think we're more likely to turn off `CheckHostIP` (the thing that spams addresses into known_hosts) in the short term, as nobody has satisfactorily explained what problem it solves to me. CIDR in ssh_config probably is less likely, as there are too many chicken and egg problems in config parsing vs address resolution.”

Comment: Link only answer. :(