# How can I use regex for hostname in ssh_config?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, configuration

So, my local address keeps on changing on my Lan.
Can't change the dhcp settings.
Addresses are all like: 192.168.A.x, 192.168.A.y, 192.168.A.z.
When I switch off the dhcp server, next time it gives 192.168.B.x, 192.168.B.y, 192.168.B.z.
It keeps x, y and z constant.

So, i have tried to edit ~/. ssh/config like this

```
Host pc1
           HostName pc.local
           User xx
           Port 22

Host pc2
           HostName "192.168.???.n1"
           User xx
           Port 22

Host pc3
           HostName "192.168.*.n2"
           User xx
           Port 22
```

Calling `ssh pc1` works fine.
Also using `ssh 192.168.A.x` with the full adress works.
But, calling `ssh pc2` gives the error `could not resolve hostname 192.168.???.n1`

Comment: Patterns can be used with `Host` but not in `Hostname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible to use regex for hostname in ssh_config, but you can use the local domain name as you had done with PC1 thus

```sh
Host pc1
           HostName pc.local
           User xx
           Port 22

Host pc2
           HostName pc2.local
           User xx
           Port 22

Host pc3
           HostName pc3.local
           User xx
           Port 22
```

using the hostname you would never need to know the IP. Then you can ssh to the hostname

```sh
ssh pc.local
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Especially not in this case. How is the ssh client supposed to "guess" what IP you want to connect to?

Set up a proper DHCP server or configure static IPs on your servers.

Comment: Got some instructions from here: https://serverfault.com/questions/803902/how-can-i-match-a-cidr-range-for-an-ssh-config-host-entry/803906

Comment: wildcard will work on `Host` line, e.g. `host 192.168.*.125<cr>user xx` would allow selecting user `xx` when using `ssh 192.168.33.125`

Comment: @Archemar, how would I then access that via ssh command?? Do I use `Host 192.168.*.n1 pc2` then `ssh pc2`??

Comment: by using `ssh 192.168.33.125` ssh can't do "retro aliasing" that DNS's work.